# Change the argument of a function that is inside another function

Tags: javascript

This are my tasks:

[image: This is my tasks]

As you can see, they all have "same" logic.
So I wanted use function like this ->

```
const task71=(x)=>Math.tan(2*x+x*x);
const main=(x,dX,xEnd)=>{
  while(x<=xEnd)
  {
    task71(x); //this part I wanna change, so it will work for task72,task73...
    x+=dX;
    console.log(`Y=${task71(x)}\nX=${x}`);
  }
}
```

This works only for `task71(x)`,but I have `task72(x),task73(x)`,etc. What do I need to change in
`main(x,dx,xEnd)` function to make it work for another functions?
I tried use `task71(x)` as argument, but in this way the function only works with the initial value of **x**.

*Perhaps this question is stupid, sorry, I recently started learning programming.*

Comment: create an object with your tasks than you can loop through them

Comment: You can pass the **name** of the function as a parameter

Comment: `const main=(x,dX,xEnd, task)=>{` and inside the main function do `task(x)`

Comment: @AlexSp3, not at their current code though, since they use `const` they can't access them via name without `eval()`. Sending function itself as an argument - that would work

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling `main`?

Comment: Like this ```main(2.40,0.20,7.60)```;

Comment: @vanowm yes I mean to pass the function as an argument, not the name as a string, I expressed badly.

Comment: @vanowm sending function itself as an argument, means ```main(func,x,dX,xEnd);```? How in this way change value of **x** for func after x+=dX?

Comment: So can you explain exactly what you need? Do you need execute a task, get result, and execute next task with the new result and continue until all task are completed?

Comment: @vanowm I want execute function main for every task.

Comment: @vanomw if I use ```task71(x)``` as parameter, like main(task71(x),x,dX,xEnd) it doesnt work correctly . Bcz in while  loop my x+=xD doesn't change for ```task71(x)```.

Comment: @ArtyomHarutyunyan How exactly are you looking for the function to work. Do you want everything to work from the same task71 function or how do you want it to work here? If its the former you can just add a if or switch case to the function and pass the 71 or 72 ,etc to identify

Comment: I want have main() function, that will change value of x[2.4;7.6](task71) or x[-5.4;1.2](task72)... and functions for every task that will run in main() function. @vanowm already solved my problem.
Thank you all very much for your help. After a long search on the Armenian forums, I didn't expect that you would help me so quickly here <3

Answer (score 1):

You can load all your taks into an object, and then execute each task in your `main`:

```js
const tasks = {
  71: (x)=>Math.tan(2*x+x*x),
  73: (x)=>Math.pow(x+1, 2),
}
const main=(x,dX,xEnd)=>{
  while(x<=xEnd)
  {
    for(let id in tasks)
    {
      let y = tasks[id](x); //this part I wanna change, so it will work for task72,task73...
      console.log(`task${id}:\nY=${y}\nX=${x}`);
    }
    x+=dX;
  }
}

main(2.40,0.20,7.60);
```

Alternatively you can pass the `task` function to the `main`:

```js
const tasks = {
  71: (x)=>Math.tan(2*x+x*x),
  73: (x)=>Math.pow(x+1, 2),
}

const main=(x,dX,xEnd, taskId)=>{
  while(x<=xEnd)
  {
    let y = tasks[taskId](x); //this part I wanna change, so it will work for task72,task73...
    x+=dX;
    console.log(`task${taskId}:\nY=${y}\nX=${x}`);
  }
}


for(let id in tasks)
{
  main(2.40,0.20,7.60, id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much <3 I did not know that objects can be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want something like this:

```
const taskmap = {
  task71: (x)=>Math.tan(2*x+x*x);
  // etcetera
};
```

And then:

```
const main=(x,dX,xEnd)=>{
  func_count = 71;
  while(x<=xEnd)
  {
    var fn = taskmap['task'+func_count];
    fn(x);
    x+=dX;
    console.log(`Y=${fn(x)}\nX=${x}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I'm bad at explaining :/